# APIs and JSON, some guidance please

Tags: json, api

Good afternoon from Scotland.

This is a shout out for some basic help on APIs and the JSON format.

I manage a team of guys who maintain and enhance a very old Debt Management system and I have been tasked with automating one of the processes that sends a list of numbers to a new dialler service. Currently, this is a manual process and involves .CSV file. The vendor who provides the dialler service has suggested that we connect via their API using JSON.

Whilst I understand the concept of APIs, I have little or no practical experience with them, having been a desk jockey for so long.

The format we've been asked to send is fairly rudimentary as is the results data.

Where I'm falling down is that I don't actually know HOW to send the info to an API!

This is the example I've been given for creating a customer record (Authorisation and Postman tokens obfuscated)

```
POST /customer/create HTTP/1.1
Host: api5.cnx1.uk
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer [[OAuth2 Token]]]
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 254666666-28b1-566669-jh65-2e6666397c5a9

{
  "token": "iuqerigu8ergroighiorguoirhgu",
  "title": "Mr",
  "first_name": "Mark",
  "middle_name": "P",
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "main_phone": "07777777777", (required)
  "alternative_phone": "01610000000",
  "address1": "99",
  "address2": "Test Street",
  "address3": "Test Grove",
  "city": "Manchester",
  "postcode": "SK9 2FG",
  "source": "Data #53h76",
  "data_list": 1992, (required)
  "date_of_birth": "1984-02-29",
  "email": "api@test.com",
  "password": "password",
  "comments": "From Rest API"
}
```

Creating records in the above format from our VB.Net-based system is easy enough, but I have no idea how to send the info.

I appreciate this is a fairly laughable question and I WILL put myself through an appropriate course, but I just need a kickstart so that I can give my Product Owners some confidence that we're progressing with it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, i suggest you spend some hours to how HTTP protocol works.
https://learn.onemonth.com/understanding-http-basics/ (not even close to be a complete source)

But, in your case, you could send these information in **body** request, remembering you can't send a body in every HTTP method.

I also suggest you download an API client (Insomnia or Postman), or use one online. Try it: https://reqbin.com/req/4rwevrqh/post-json-example

It seems you are trying it in Postman, so when you create a request and choose "POST" method.   Just under the place where you put your URL request, you have an option called "body", where you can paste your json, and it should work